# WordPress subdirectory installation with Tomcat using nginx webserver

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I'm running tomcat on main website using nginx proxy pass, now I want to install wordpress on the same domain as a sub-directory like this: `example.com/blog`

I used below config in nginx.

```
location /blog {

   root       /home/blog/html;
   index index.php index.htm index.html;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;


   }
  location ~ \.php$ {
        root     /home/blog/html;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 200;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/blog-php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
   location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires 30d;
    }
```

When I visit `example.com/blog` the WordPress installation page will go like this

`http://example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php`

How can I properly install wordpress with Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `wordpress` that it lives in a subdirectory. I use `wp-config.php` rather than the dashboard, and I don't include the scheme or domain name:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', '/blog' );
define( 'WP_HOME', '/blog' );
```